# Custom Control DataContext Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **Custom Controller** that works fine like this:

```xml
<Controller:DLBox ID="{Binding SHVM.Selected.ID}" />
```

I mean binding `ID` to a property in `ViewModel`. But when I want to bind it like this:

```xml
<ScrollViewer DataContext="{Binding SHVM.Selected}">
    <Controller:DLBox ID="{Binding ID}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Binding to **DataContext** of parent, It doesn't work at all. I have some other **Custom Controllers** and they do fine, But I don't know what the hell is this one's problem!

This is the controller:

```
public partial class DLBox : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty IDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(int), typeof(DLBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                (o, e) => (o as DLBox).IDPropertyChanged((int)e.NewValue)));
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private void IDPropertyChanged(int e)
    {
        ID = e;
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell my what's wrong? Because I'm debugging for 6 hours straight and didn't find anything! Thanks a lot.
‌
‌
**UPDATE:**
That worked with just adding:

```xml
<... DataContext={Binding} .../>
```

And I don't know why!
Now the real problem is that I want to use this inside 2 **ItemsControls** and even with **DataContext** Still doesn't work.
*(Just for clarification, I have 2 Lists inside each other. Think about the first one like 10 schools **First List**, and inside each school there is some studens **Second List**)*

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=SHVM.Extra.Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Controller:DLBox DataContext="{Binding}" ID="{Binding ID}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
ID is just a `TextBlock` In a `UserControl`. There is nothing that I can show here!
 All I did, Just set the **Text** of `TextBlock` inside the PropertyCallBack (Didn't use MVVM inside my controllers):

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="txtIDValue"/>
```

And inside CodeBehind:

```
private void IDPropertyChanged(string e)
{
    ID= e;
    txtIDValue.Text = e;
}
```

There is nothing relevant to this problem, And that's why I couldn't figure it out!
Appreciate any help.

**ANSWER:**
After 12 hours working on it, I find out that It was an idiotic mistake! I don't know why and when I set `DataContext` in my Controller's **XAML**!
Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: As a note, you should not do something like `(o as DLBox).IDPropertyChanged(...)`, because in case `o` is not a `DLBox` it would wrongly throw a `NullReferenceException`, while you would expext an `InvalidCastException`. The expression should instead be `((DLBox)o).IDPropertyChanged(...)`. Anyway, you don't need it at all.

Comment: Is there something in your `DLBox` where you explicitly set its DataContext, e.g. `DataContext = this;` in the constructor?

Comment: @Clemens Nope! I have to set that too? I didn't know about it. **Edit: **Although it doesn't work!

Comment: No you don't have to. I just asked, because it's a frequently made mistake when people create UserControls.

Comment: From what you've shown in your question, both the `DataContext="{Binding}"`, at the inner ItemsControl and the DLBox, should be redundant. Such an expression is almost always redundant because it just sets the current DataContext to itself. The exception is when the DataContext was (wrongly) set explicitly before, so that it isn't inherited from the control's parent.

Comment: @Clemens That's my exact point! Why it works with DataContext="{Binding}"? But inside ItemsControls doesn't work?!

Comment: How do you know that it "doesn't work" and what exactly does that mean? Is DLBox doing anything with the ID property value?

Comment: @Clemens It suppose to show ID on screen, Like a TextBlock (Of course more complicated). But it doesn't set the value at all. (Tested with breakpoint)

Comment: I guess you tested with a breakpoint on the CLR setter, right? That won't be hit, because the setter isn't called when the value is set by a Binding (and some other sources). Instead, WPF directly calls SetValue. You might show how DLBox actually visualizes the ID value, i.e. the internal TextBlock Binding

Comment: @Clemens One of the reasons I used PropertyCallBack was this. Inside the method I can set the breakpoint and it works fine. Also, as you said I can see ID on screen and it's empty!

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with the source property. We can't help you when you don't provide sufficient information. Show us the relevant parts of the DLBox control, and also how the view model property is implemented.

Comment: @Clemens There is nothing relevant, But see my Update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependency property declaration is wrong, because the getter and setter of the CLR wrapper must call the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods respectively. Besides that, your PropertyChangedCallback is redundant. There is no need to set the property again in a callback that is called when the property value has just been set.

The declaration should look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ID", typeof(int), typeof(DLBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public int ID
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(IDProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IDProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet! Also, I used this solution before, And now again, And it doesn't work at all. I know my method is redundant, But I had to use it that way.